# property in HttpRequest changes unexpectedly between Backend and Frontend

Tags: angular

I'm a bit lost here...
When I send a request from my Angular frontend to my java backend, and the backend responds with a `response.communicationStatus="FAILURE"`, the result in the Frontend API is always received with a `response.communicationStatus="SUCCESS"`. How can that be?

This is the Angular request:

```
this.httpClient.post<SnowLoadResponseDTO>(`${this.basePath}/computeSnowLoad`,
            body,
            {
                withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
                headers: headers,
                observe: observe,
                reportProgress: reportProgress
            }
        );

export class SnowLoadResponseDTO {
    communicationStatus?: string;
}
```

this is the simple backend API (java):

```
@POST
    @Path("/computeSnowLoad")
    public SnowLoadResponseDTO computeSnowLoad(SnowLoadRequestDTO request) {
      return new SnowLoadResponseDTO(CommunicationStatus.FAILURE.name());
    }

public enum CommunicationStatus {
    SUCCESS, FAILURE,
}
```

I double checked for typos and the backend returns SUCCESS (tested with Postman).